# Getting Null Uri on ContentResolver's insert() method with MediaStore

Tags: android, mediastore, scoped-storage

I am trying to add an image file to the MediaStore and then use the Uri from the ContentResolver's insert method to open an OutputStream as follows:

```
    ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "my_file_name");
    cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    String relativePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;
    cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, relativePath);

    Uri pictureCollectionUri;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        pictureCollectionUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    }
    else{
        pictureCollectionUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    Uri picturesMediaUri = resolver.insert(pictureCollectionUri, cv);

    try {
        outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(picturesMediaUri);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
```

The picturesMediaUri variable returns always null on a device running Android 9 so I cannot open an OutputStream.

The app has File read and write permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would only use that code on Android 10 and higher. Just write the image to external storage directly on older devices.

Comment: Thanks, CommonsWare.  That was fast.  I was following the example in the Android Developer's documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#java.   So are the docs incorrect in their handling of this on Android < 10 ?

Comment: When the Android 10 approach came out, I think I tried it on 9.0 and ran into the same basic problem that you did. So, I went with `MediaStore` for 10+ and classic file I/O on older devices. See [this sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/blob/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt), though it's in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take it that the docs are incorrect - maybe because things got delayed with scoped storage and covid-19.  I'll mark your answer as correct!